# PHP + AJAX + JQuery + Login & Shaking Modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm a noob in the PHP + AJAX field, but I'm trying to implement a login procedure for a project.
The problem is that I'm not able to get AJAX to work, and I need that to execute the function "**shakeModalWrongPassword();**".
If I simply call my "**login.php**" in the index file using

```
<?php include_once('login.php'); ?>
```

I'm not having any problem: I can login and everything is smooth.
When I try to use AJAX, the login procedure doesn't work and my target of being able to shake that modal - if a user inserts a wrong  Username/Password combination - crashes on an steel wall. :D

Any help?
At the moment I've written this code:

**HTML**

*index.php*

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['user_login'])) {
  $user = $_SESSION["user_login"];
  header("location: home.php");
} else {
  $user = "";
}
?>

<div class="form loginBox">
  <form id="loginform" method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input id="username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
    <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
    <input id="login" class="btn btn-default btn-login" type="submit" value="Login" name="login">
  </form>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#loginform').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'login.php',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
          window.location = 'home.php';
        } else {
          shakeModalWrongPassword();
        }
      }
    });
  });
});

function shakeModalWrongPassword() {
  $('#loginModal .modal-dialog').addClass('shake');

  $('.error').addClass('alert alert-danger').html("Combinazione username/password non valida.");
  $('input[type="password"]').val('');

  setTimeout(function () {
    $('#loginModal .modal-dialog').removeClass('shake');
  }, 1000);
}
```

**PHP**

*connect.php*

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'wildgramdb');

$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE)
        or die("Errore nella connessione al database: " . mysql_error());
?>
```

*login.php*

```
<?php
include_once("connect.php");

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $user_login = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
    $password_login = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
    $hashed_password = md5($password_login);

    $check_user_account = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$user_login' and password = '$hashed_password'");
    $user_count = mysqli_num_rows($check_user_account);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($check_user_account, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        if ($user_count == 1) {
            $id = $row["id"];
            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
            $_SESSION["user_login"] = $user_login;
            $_SESSION["password_login"] = $password_login;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: "When I try to use AJAX, the login procedure doesn't work" wait can you describe what happens?

Comment: @ScriptKitty, hi.
In few words, the user is not redirected to the home.php and the modal is not shaked when the Username/Password combination is wrong.
The redirection is successful if I don't use AJAX, but in that case I can't use the shaking feature for my modal.
I hope I have been clear, it's pretty hard to explain just by words.

Comment: The Firebug extension for Firefox is a big help with AJAX debugging.  You'll want to pay attention to the 'Console' tab of Firebug, which will show you all your AJAX requests, what data is returned, and whether or not the data is what javascript expects.  Most browsers have something similar, but I've found Firebug to be the best.

Comment: @SuperJer, thanks for your reply.
I've tried with Firebug (I've been using it, too), but no error comes from the Console. I think that my problem is in the code I've written, but I can't understand where.

Comment: You should be able to expand the response body of the ajax call in the console to see if PHP is responding with errors.  If this isn't happening, enabling PHP error reporting may help.

Comment: @SuperJer, the problem is that I'm a noob in AJAX programming and I'm really stuck. My code doesn't seem to give back any error: I'm looking everywhere, but my low knowledge in this field is embarrassing.
I'm available to send my code to everyone whom could help me to sort out the problem. This work is just a school project I'm working on, so I would not be angry if someone steal some ideas from it (even if I greatly doubt so). :D

Comment: In Firebug you can also check to make sure the correct data is being fed to the AJAX call.  In the console, when you click 'Login', you should see a line like `POST http://domain/login.php`.  Expanding that line, check the 'Post' tab to make sure your form is correctly being serialized and sent to the server for evaluation.

Comment: @SuperJer, playing a little around with AJAX, now, when I click on Login, the Username and the Password are being showed in the URL at the top of the page in the form:

    ?username=USERNAME&password=PSWD&login=Login

Still, the Login procedure doesn't work.